# Remote view to To Hyper-V Guest Virtual Machines

Tags: virtualization, vnc, remote-access, hyper-v

My software can discover all the hyperv vms (a software agent is installed in the hyperv host which returns the information). From my software I can do any operation on the vm. Now I want to take a remote of the hyperv vms from my software. It can be a web based or flash based or any other way.... How to accomplish this ?

Comment: "take a remote" is not clear.  Can you expand on what you mean?

Comment: oops! typo. Hi uSlackr, I want to take the remote console view of the vm.